# Accuracy of History Channel's The Bible

Tags: bible, history, non-christians

I am very interested in learning about Christianity and would like to purchase History Channel's [The Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AMR5LZA).

How close is this to the actual scriptures? Is this series a good introduction to Christianity to non-Christians?

Answer (score 3):

How closely the movie is to Scripture depends on which Translation and which Denomination you are asking about.

The producers of the film are a Catholic couple and the movie compares quite closely to the Doughy Rheims translation. There are some striking differences between the Bible canons of Catholicism and Protestantism, but as far as the story of Jesus death and resurrection there are very minor disagreements.

I have made a dedicated study of the Scriptures of the Holy Bible for more than a decade, and I found no major complaints about the depictions in the Movie.

It must be considered that to take words on a page and turn that into something visual is going to be flavored by the imagination of the person making the depiction, and their concept may vary widely from other conceptions. Just take for instance the background, what you may have pictured is a semi desert scene while I may have imagined a wooded area.

The story lines are as far as I can tell very close to the scriptures. I personally feel that it is an excellent movie for someone wanting to learn about the Bible, and particularly the story of the Gospel. The portrayal of the Gospel is closer to the Book of Mark than the books of the other three Gospels.

You also might explore some of the Biblical movies presented on You tube. There are some excellent presentations available there and they can be downloaded free so that you can watch them at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

They take quite a bit of creative license with the series. The message is essentially right, but many of the details are skewed. For example, Samson was not a big, burly African.

Comment: How do you know that Samson was not a big , burly black man? Of course we all know he was not an African because he was a Jew, but there is no way to know what color his skin was since the Bible does not tell us that.

Comment: The clothing that they wear- he and his mother- suggests that they are Africans. I never said he couldn't have been black.

Comment: Not to try to ride a dead horse but how do you know what garb Africans wore during that period? Since the world was settled by the tribes derived from the three sons of Noah, how much difference would be found in the clothing of those nations other than climatic considerations?

Comment: The clothing uses patterns that are similar to the clothing of the proud African heritage, id est, bold colors and lots of right angles.